# A joke on existentialism

Tags: existence, existentialism

First can somebody explain me the meaning of "Existentialism" in a layman's term. I looked up Wikipedia and some other sites but I am not getting the definition.

In an episode of '*Criminal Minds*', a character, Dr. Spencer Reid (a genius with 3 Ph.D's, one in philosophy too) cracks a joke in a classroom which no one gets except one or two, and he himself laugh pretty hard.

***JOKE-***
 "How many existentialists does it take to screw in a lightbulb?  **Two.**
One to change the lightbulb, and one to observe how it symbolizes an incandescent beacon of subjectivity in a netherworld of cosmic nothingness."

Please explain what existentialism is, and what this joke means?

Comment: It suggests that existential questions are useless.